# Filtering row with sub queries if column result is null

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Here is my current WIP query:

```
select 
    iclaim_id,
    (select SUM(AuthAmtLineItems) as AuthAmt
     from
         (select 
              cauth_total as AuthAmtLineItems
          from  
              claim_details_history
          where 
              iclaim_id = cd.iclaim_id
              and iclaim_det_status_id = 2
              and btcovered_flag = 1
          group by 
              irecord_id, sdetail_type, sdetail_desc, cauth_total) AuthAmt 
     having 
         SUM(AuthAmtLineItems) > 750) as AuthAmt
from 
    claim_details_history cd
where 
    iclaim_det_status_id = 2
    and btcovered_flag = 1
group by 
    iclaim_id
having 
    min(dtupdate_last) between '02/05/2015 00:00:00.000' and '02/05/2015 23:59:59.997'
```

And here is the result set:

```
iclaim_id   AuthAmt
67712   3500.00
71054   NULL
71032   NULL
71096   NULL
68824   NULL
71039   NULL
71071   NULL
67863   NULL
71098   NULL
70437   1500.00
71048   NULL
71037   NULL
71080   NULL
71035   NULL
71049   NULL
71118   NULL
71053   759.14
```

What I am trying and failing to do is removing the rows that have NULL in them or `having SUM(AuthAmtLineItems) > 750` whichever option would be easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `correlated subquery` use `cross apply`

```
SELECT iclaim_id,
       AuthAmt
FROM   claim_details_history cd
       CROSS apply (SELECT Sum(AuthAmtLineItems) AS AuthAmt
                    FROM   (SELECT cauth_total AS AuthAmtLineItems
                            FROM   claim_details_history
                            WHERE  iclaim_id = cd.iclaim_id
                                   AND iclaim_det_status_id = 2
                                   AND btcovered_flag = 1
                            GROUP  BY irecord_id,
                                      sdetail_type,
                                      sdetail_desc,
                                      cauth_total) AuthAmt
                    HAVING Sum(AuthAmtLineItems) > 750) cs
WHERE  iclaim_det_status_id = 2
       AND btcovered_flag = 1
GROUP  BY iclaim_id
HAVING Min(dtupdate_last) BETWEEN '02/05/2015 00:00:00.000' AND '02/05/2015 23:59:59.997'
```

Comment: Is there any way to make this go faster?  My `correlated subquery` ran in less than a second but this `cross apply` took 50 seconds to run.  It works however!  I had to add `AuthAmt` to your `GROUP BY` clause.